# Why does my configure method in Securityconfig not work?

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, endpoint

I am working on a spring boot RESTful API and I have a problem that I can't seem to solve.

In my WebSecurityConfig I have the configure method that looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()//So we can send post requests without being rejected(if we using form based indication we want to enable this)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**")
            .permitAll()//any request that goes trough that end point we want to allow.
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and().addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

}
```

When I want to use the endpoint `/login` I would do it like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()//So we can send post requests without being rejected(if we using form based indication we want to enable this)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**")
            .permitAll()//any request that goes trough that end point we want to allow.
            .anyRequest().
            .authenticated().and().formLogin();

}
```

This works, but then the piece of code that was there before is gone and so some of my functionality within my code.

So I basically want to combine formLogin with the code that I had.

**What I have tried:**

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()//So we can send post requests without being rejected(if we using form based indication we want to enable this)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**")
            .permitAll()//any request that goes trough that end point we want to allow.
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated().and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and().addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class).formLogin();

}
```

But this did not work. It got me this error when I requested `/login` :

```
{"timestamp":"2021-03-29T12:37:35.948+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/login"}
```

Also this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()//So we can send post requests without being rejected(if we using form based indication we want to enable this)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**")
            .permitAll()//any request that goes trough that end point we want to allow.
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated().and().formLogin().and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and().addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

}
```

But this gave me this error:

```
{"timestamp":"2021-03-29T12:39:35.872+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/login"}
```

Comment: Your rules don't make sense `antMatcher(`/**`).permitAll()` means allow everything and `anyRequest().authenticated()` which means allow everything but authenticated. The latter overrides the former. (`anyRequest()` == `antMatcher(`/**`)`. If it is REST why would you need the `/login` in the first place? That should be part of your filter or JWT Authentication Filter not the regular Form login.

Comment: I allow everything because I am working on the project. In the end I want to replace the /** with register and authenticate